# How to extract the final slug of a url without trailing slash in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a bunch of URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/XX/YY/cat/this-url-has-12345/
https://www.example.com/XX/YY/cat/this-url-has-different-length-67891/
```

I am trying to extract the slug (everything after /cat/) but without the ending trailing slash. Though, failing to get rid of the trailing slash.

I am using the below function but can't seem to negate an index to avoid the trailing slash:

```
RIGHT(C2;FIND("/cat/";C2;1))
```

All slugs would be in different length though the pattern before slug would be same.

Any functions to get only the slug without trailing slash? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MID`:

`=MID(C2,FIND("/cat/",C2)+5,LEN(C2)-4-FIND("/cat/",C2)-(RIGHT(C2)="/"))`

or in your locale:

`=MID(C2;FIND("/cat/";C2)+5;LEN(C2)-4-FIND("/cat/";C2)-(RIGHT(C2)="/"))`

- `MID` arg 2: It finds the `/cat/` and extracts the sequence from the string after that (`+5`).
- `MID` arg 3: Extract length is the length of the rest of the string, minus 1 character depending on whether or not it ends with a slash.

Comment: one word. Genius!! Thanks a bunch.